# AKS Helm Install - Not Authorized after connecting with ACR

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-acr

I have a AKS and ACR, and attached the ACR successfully with my AKS using

```
az aks update -n <AKSNAME> -g <RESOURCE> --attach-acr <ACRNAME>
```

Yet, when I run the command below from [this how-to-guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip#create-an-ingress-controller), I get a `Error: failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition`. Upon further investigating with `kubectl get events`, I find that the images I pull from ACR are failing due to authorization: `failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized`.

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set controller.image.image=$CONTROLLER_IMAGE \
    --set controller.image.tag=$CONTROLLER_TAG \
    --set controller.image.digest="" \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.image=$PATCH_IMAGE \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.tag=$PATCH_TAG \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set defaultBackend.image.image=$DEFAULTBACKEND_IMAGE \
    --set defaultBackend.image.tag=$DEFAULTBACKEND_TAG \
    --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=$STATIC_IP \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"=$DNS_LABEL
```

I find this very strange, cause I have the images in my ACR, and I have successfully authenticated ACR with AKS.

I run everything from the Azure CLI, Helm version 3.4.0. I found some related issues, which all use the `attach-acr`.